# NativeScript TAB button double functionalaty

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

We need for our mobile application to bind two events on tab. When loaded it needs to load a page, and on click on the same button it needs to change the view. 
The problem is that, when TAB page, when it is rendered, can't get another event handler when new page is inserted, if am not wrong. IONIC can achieve this functionality, but we need nativescript.

Any idea how?!

thnx

Answer (score 1):

To add any addition tap handlers that you want, is fairly simple in NativeScript.   I'm not sure I understand your question or use-case; but to add another tap handler (assuming you want the tap event)

You can use:
     `element.on('tap', anotherTapHandler);`

To get the element you can use the built in `view.getViewById('id')` or you can use a plugin like my [Nativescript-Dom](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom) plugin (disclaimer: I'm the auther) to do things like `getElementsByClassName('MyButton')[0].on('tap', anotherTapHandler);`  or the additional helper functions that find all elements and run your function against each one...  `runAgainstTagNames('Button', function(element) { element.on('tap', anotherTapHandler); });`